# Whats the best way to "merge" objects like these

Tags: modeling

Im new to Blender and i am having problems with trying to "merge" these objects, whats the best way to do it. Its for a game so just putting them together would waste tris if i understand everything correctly (Since there will be faces inside the object)

[image: Objects]

Comment: I don't really understand how could the fact that it's for the game interfere with leaving objects as separate ones. You should stick to way which assumes lower amount of geometry while giving the same quality. If you join them you should reconstruct topology as most likely you don't want Ngons in game. If you leave them separate just fill the back side of the cylinder with triangle fan; chances are it'll have less geometry compared to joining.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way I know:

1. Add three loop cuts to the blocky object in both directions.
2. Delete the four middle faces
3. Snap the vertices to the octagonal object.
4. go to Object Mode
5. join the objects
6. Remove doubles

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my admittedly limited experience, I would do something like this:

1. In Object Mode, select both objects with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>.

   - Select the one whose origin you want to keep last.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the objects.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into Edit Mode.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enable snapping.

   - Use "vertex" snapping mode, with the "closest" setting.
5. Press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering the octagonal prism to select the island.
6. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to translate along Z axis.
7. Hover one of the vertices of the face you're trying to snap to.
8. Go into face select mode, select the face you just snapped to, and press <kbd>X</kbd> to "Delete faces".
9. Join the top vertices of the octagonal prism with the four vertices of the face you just deleted in whatever formation of triangles / quads makes the most sense for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi qwertyqywterqwerty,

I am not a professional myself so this might not be completely perfect.

Here is what to do:

**First:** Select the bigger object, go to the 'Modifier' tab and select 'Booleen'.

**Second:** Change the 'Operation' from 'Intersect' to 'Union' and select the smaller object in the 'Object' tab.

**Third:** Align the smaller object exactly to the bigger object.

**Fourth:** After aligning it perfectly, click 'Apply' on the modifier.

**Fifth:** Drag away the newly joined mesh and delete the old smaller object.

**Sixth:** Your Done!

After doing all this you could do some more minor editing if needed.

Well, I hoped this was clear and helped!I was going to post images, but I have to few reputation stuff so I couldn't. If you still have question feel free to ask.

Good luck with your game and cheers!